# Show right border on inner iframe which is being cut off on 100% width

Tags: html, css, iframe

Am I missing something with this setup, with an iframe within an iframe and the border being cut off on the right on the inner iframe?

https://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/widgets/v1/bracketspage?eventid=30

[image]

Comment: The width is set to 100% (inline style).  Try using `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the iframe's box sizing to use border box, it will include the border and padding when setting the `width` property:

```
iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: That worked, since I was using bootstrap less I used, `.box-sizing(border-box);`

Answer (score 1):

You can not use width 100% if you want to show the full border. Border always goes around the region. SO you can try using a fixed width like `width: 938px;` or `width: 99%;`

From @davidpauljunior `box-sizing: border-box;` i like it.